# Solr multiword facets don't show up

Tags: indexing, solr, whitespace, search-multiple-words

I have an index that it's size is more than 4GB. So re-indexing costs too much for me.

I'm trying to show facets of search word. My facet_field is "category". Some of documents have multiple words in their category fields. However, Solr does not display multiple word facets. Indexing had been done with WhiteSpaceTokenizer.

I searched in internet and I could not find any solution except re-indexing.

Is there a way to display multiple word facets without re-indexing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, "Faceting is done on **indexed** rather than stored values"

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview#line-9

Answer (score 0):

You want to try and design your solr setup so reindexing everything is possible, for situations like this one.

You can build a new index while the old one is still running and swap the new one into place.